# {Bindable on function/ methods

Tags: apache-flex

Can we put **[Bindable]** on **functions/methods**?  I know that bindable is used to change the value of the source property to destination property.  But not sure if we can use that for methods.  Can you guys give me reason why we cannot put/ if we can then what will be the outcome?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can you guys give me reason why we cannot put/ if we can then what
>   will be the outcome?

You can use Bindable on get/set properties; which are implemented as methods. Sort of like this:

```
private var _myValue : Boolean;

[Bindable(event='myValueChanged']
public function get myValue():Boolean{
  return _myValue;
}
public function set myValue(value:Boolean):void{
  _myValue = value;
  dispatchEvent(new Event('myValueChanged'));
}
```

[Disclaimer I wrote this code in the browser]

The purpose of Binding is to 'magically' link two properties together.  So, when the source property changes, the destination property also changes.

How are you expecting to apply this concept to a function?

Comment: This question was asked by an interviewer.  I knew that we could not apply it to methods but, I couldnt justify myself.  But one thing is I didnt even think about setters and getters :)  Thanks!!

Comment: It could have been a trick question.  Or he could have wondered if you ever did a a review of -keep-generated-actionscript code to see how binding works.  Under the hood it's done with events and event listeners (AKA Functions).

Comment: Why do you need to have it dispatch and event and have the getter have a linked bindable event?  Just `[Bindable]` on the getting will work.

Comment: Of course you can use bindable methods.  This is very clearly documented! http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=databinding_2.html .  He/She was probably checking to see if you knew when to dispatch custom binding events to make sure binding occurs in circumstances where the "vanilla" binding provided by Flex isn't enough.

Comment: @J_A_X I do believe you're right.  However, manually dispatching the changed event is the approach used internally to the Flex Framework; so I just learned (and copied) their convention in my own development.  I believe doing so creates clearly documented code.

Comment: @AmyBlankenship I always forget about that. I don't think I've ever seen it used in practice.  Here is a direct link to the page: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/databinding_4.html#199771

Comment: I've only used it once...when I had a data Class that represented a text object, including all the styling information.  It had a toCSSStyleDeclaration method before I realized I'd need to have that update whenever any of the style properties changed.  I had it bindable on a custom event that was dispatched whenever any property changed.

Comment: @Flextras:  private var _myValue : Boolean;

[Bindable(event='myValueChanged']
public function get myValue():Boolean{
  return _myValue;
}
public function set myValue(value:Boolean):void{
  _myValue = value;
}
What will happen in this scenario, if you are trying to change the property of the _myValue

Comment: Nothing will happen in terms of binding, because _myValue is a private property that is not declared as Bindable in the code.